# Python Tkinter terminal integration

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, terminal, tkinter

I am trying to integrate a terminal in my Python script. I eventually got it working, but it shows a red bar at the left-hand side and I wanted to get rid of it.

[image: Screenshot showing issue]

The code is this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
root.title("My Program")
Terminal = Frame(root, height = 400, width = 500)
Terminal.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = YES)
winfo = Terminal.winfo_id()
os.system("xterm -into %d -geometry 40x200 -sb &" % winfo)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: (http://s28.postimg.org/xpwkvqp0d/Screenshot_from_2015_04_21_17_16_16.png)

Comment: the red bar on the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red bar on the left is xterm's scrollbar.  Drop the `-sb` option from the command to eliminate that:

```
os.system("xterm -into %d -geometry 40x200 &" % winfo)
```

The [manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h2-OPTIONS) says

> **`-sb`**
>
> This option indicates  that  some  number  of  lines  that  are
> scrolled  off  the top of the window should be saved and that a
> scrollbar should be  displayed  so  that  those  lines  can  be
> viewed.   This  option  may  be  turned on and off from the "VT
> Options" menu.